# Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed. eX going again

Tags: bibtex, miktex

My bibtex works properly. But in my main file when I chose `pdflatex+makeindex+bibtex`, it gives me this error:

```
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\PhD student\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\texify.log
```

If I just run

```
 pdflatex
```

it run the pdf file, not completely. Just from the introduction and without references.
What should I do.

```
\documentclass{aa}  
\usepackage{array}  
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, 
            amsmath,  
            siunitx}  
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{txfonts}

\begin{document} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have an `aa.cls` file in your folder? If not, you should change `\documentclass{aa}` to something meaningful.

Comment: Yes yes I have it.

Comment: Ooh, sorry for the noise then. But if I replace `aa` by, say, `article`, the document compiles. Are you sure the problem isn't in this `aa.cls`? Can you add that to your question, please?

Comment: but aa is the format of the journal that I am using their template. I don´t know if it will be no problem if I change it to article

Comment: What I meant is that if `article` works and with `aa` doesn't, then the problem is with the `aa.cls` file. If you showe this `aa.cls` file it would be easier to find you what the problem is. The log file might be useful as well.

Comment: Don't use texify if you get errors. Its error messages are nearly useless. Run pdflatex and bibtex individually.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I am sorry but I don´t know how to add aa.cls file into my question.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer but when I run them individually, in my paper there is no references and just (??)

Comment: @Yasamin You can give us a link to that file or you can edit it in your question as code. Wither way works.

Comment: Show the content of the blg-file.

Comment: the file is so big and in the question I can not put the whole code. So I am trying to find a way to do it

Comment: The `blg`-file shouldn't be very big, unless you have lots of references with errors.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry to ask this, the blg-file is the bibtex file? Should I add this to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i SOLVED THIS PROBLEM BY USING THIS METHOD:

I am using texmaker as the editor. I compile it as following:

```
pdflatex filename (with or without extensions)
bibtex filename (without extensions)
pdflatex filename (with or without extensions)
pdflatex filename (with or without extensions)
```

THEN IT WORKED PROPERLY.

Comment: By this way, I mean compiling the file by this order, my problem solved. That´s why I put it as an answer!!!

Comment: Oh, I got it. OK! However, next time you should put some lines like "I solved this problem myself after doing blah blah"!

Answer (score -1):

In case it helps someone else, I updated the packages on the Miktex installation and reconfigured and that fixed the problem for me...*phew*